# Django teacher-student model filtering data

Tags: python, html, django

I have a user model in Django in which the usertype field is "administrator" for teachers and "student" otherwise.

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    email = models.EmailField(unique=False)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=25, unique=True) 
    password = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    usertype = models.CharField(max_length=140, null=True)
    teacher = models.ForeignKey(
                    settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
                    on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                    null = True
                    )
    objects = UserManager()
```

I also have a Django model for student data:

```
class Row(models.Model): 
    user = models.TextField(max_length=500, blank=True)
    question = models.TextField(max_length=500, blank=True)
    answer = models.TextField(max_length=500, blank=True)
```

When a teacher is logged in, I display their list of students and want them to be able to view a copy of the student's data (a modal should pop up).

```
<table>
    <h2>Students Directory: </h2>
        <tr>
           <th>Name</th>
           <th>Email</th>
           <th>Download Data</th>
        </tr>
        {% for student in usertable %}
        <tr> 
            <td>{{ student.first_name }} {{ student.last_name}} </td>
            <td>{{ student.email }}</td>
            <td><a onclick="viewData({{student.username}});"> Download Link </a></td>
       </tr>
         {% endfor %}
</table>
```

So, I pass the student's username into viewData() and that should pop up the modal. However, the function is written in javascript and I can't do something like - "Row.objects.all.filter(username=username)". However, I can't pass the already filtered object into the profile.html because I don't know which student's username I will need.

There's probably an easy solution to this that I'm missing somewhere.

TLDR - in my profile.html project I want to click a button and pop up a modal with my Django model filtered by a certain username (which can vary)

Comment: There is a couple of options to do this: the simplest one: why dont you just put a link to a view that shows the necessary data? Will not be modal but do you really need this?

Comment: @ger.s.brett Yes, I would prefer a modal. However, how a link to a view fix this? I still need to filter the model by the selected student and this is not the same user that is the one logged in. The teacher should be able to click the different links to view each students' data and having a view for each student is not optimal..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple solution would be:

```
<td><a href="openlink/{{student.username}}"> Download Link </a></td>
```

And then you create a view  in your views.py (that you need to link up in the urls.py);

```
from django.shortcuts import render
def openlink(request, username):
    rows=Row.objects.filter(user = username) 
    return render(request, 'rows_detail.html', {'rows': rows})
```

The template has to be able to work with the rows variable.

I want to remark, that it would be better to have a user filed on the row model instead of the text field.

```
urlpatterns = [....
path('openlink/<str:username>/', openlink, name="openlink"),]
```

Comment: That seems pretty simple. I'm kind of new to Django so I'm not sure how to set up the url. Does the view know that {{student.username}} in "openlink/{{student.username}} is the "username" parameter? I have - url(r'^openlink/$', views.openlink, name='openlink') - and it's not recognizing the .../profile/openlink/username_here format

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options here,

1- Is to add an ajax call to when you click the button, which gets the specific user data from the server like so, so you would need a function on the server to handle that as well. For example,

in js (assuming Jquery is used)

```
$.ajax(url_to_student_info_view).done(function() {
    // js to fill data in the modal html
})
```

in your views,

```
from django.core import serializers

def get_student_info(request, student_id):
    return HttpResponse(serializers.serialize('json', [ Row.objects.get(pk=student_id), ]))   # very rough but dont forget to check of the user exists before your return
```

2- Your other option is to create a modal for each student info, so, in your html,

```
{% for student in students %}
<div class="modal" id="student-{{ student.id }}">
    <!-- student info here -->
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

then your js function would basically open that modal based on the ID of the provided as `student-ID`.

Which one should you use?

Both would work, the first one is the approach I would take since the second might increase the size of the DOM drastically depending on the number of students.

Hope this helps!